# PySpark: Get nth value of tuple for UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've a UDF function with output in tuple format. I want to apply that UDF to my input column and based on what I need out, I want to choose either out1 or out2 value as the value for my column.

Something like this:

```
def my_f(inp):
   return out1,out2

df =  df.withColumn('first_val', F.udf(my_f, StringType())(F.col('inp_col'))[0]
df =  df.withColumn('second_val', F.udf(my_f, StringType())(F.col('inp_col'))[1]
```

I want the `first_val` col to have first element of tuple, and `second_val` to have second element of the tuple. *This code of course doesn't work.*

I tried it by passing the required part of tuple as function input and it worked. Like this:

```
def my_f(inp, out='full'):
   if out=='first':
      return out1
   elif out=='second':
      return out2
   else: # case 'full'
   return out1,out2

df =  df.withColumn('first_val',  F.udf(my_f, StringType())(F.col('inp_col'), F.col('inp_col'))
df =  df.withColumn('second_val', F.udf(my_f, StringType())(F.col('inp_col'),'F.col('second'))
```

But is there a simpler way of getting the nth element of tuple within the line without passing this parameter?

Comment: It is not clear where `out1` and `out2` are defined. Anyway, you can define `my_f` to accept a parameter and return a function that return nth element of the tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UDF is returning a tuple you should change your return type to `ArrayType(StringType)` assuming you are returning a tuple of Strings. Then you will be able to access the first and second element of your tuple by using the `[n]` notation. Here is an example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
...
@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.StringType())
def my_f(inp):
   ...
   return (out1, out2)

df =  df.withColumn('first_val', my_f('inp_col')[0])
df =  df.withColumn('second_val', my_f('inp_col')[1])
```

In case you need different types in your tuple you might want to consider returning a `StructType` instead. Here would be an example where the first element of the tuple is a string and the second is an integer:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
...
@F.udf(T.StructType([
    T.StructField("first", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("second", T.IntegerType())
]))
def my_f(inp):
   ...
   return {"first": out1, "second": out2}

df =  df.withColumn('first_val', my_f('inp_col')["first"])
df =  df.withColumn('second_val', my_f('inp_col')["second"])
```